# How to integrate Google reCAPTCHA in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am working on an iOS project the client requirement is to put the  Google reCAPTCHA authentication in the registration form.so, is there any way that I can do it as an android or website. I searched a lot but I didn't get any specific exact solution of Google reCAPTCHA in Swift. I am currently using Swift latest version I,e Swift - 5,

[image: form image link here]

Comment: have a look at this [Github library](https://github.com/fjcaetano/ReCaptcha)

Comment: There are some libraries for that (such as https://github.com/fjcaetano/ReCaptcha). but what is the purpose behind it? this is something that usually we don't do on iOS.

Comment: I Agree. ReCAPTCHA is a pretty awful user experience and not the sort of low-friction experience that Apple users expect.

Comment: Reference for future query: https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/142

Comment: I tried it already but it is not working for me.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: any update on this. I have done this but web view captcha frame issue.can you help me or any demo.

Answer (score 6):

[I wrote a Gist](https://gist.github.com/jkereako/d111ff6f4594873d409d3194371d6732) that shows how to incorporate reCAPTCHA v2 in Swift. It's a simple solution (MVVM pattern using delegates) with an explanation on how to use it.